# connect to groupwise mbox with mutt

Tags: imap, novell, mutt, groupwise, mbox

I am try to extract the GroupWise mailbox userlist and emails via script.
I am told that Groupwise is in mbox format mutt looks for .maildir which does not exist on a Novell server.
How can I administratively access the Groupwise mbox via the command line for scripting?
I am trying to do a backend/manual migration.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to go the hard way, eh? ;-)

(we took Quest back than, it was worth it)

The only other way I'd know for connecting to mailboxes: IMAP. But: You'd have to do this via every one's account (and credentials).

There's no possibility to manually copy files from the GW storage directory, you won't be able to read (extract/merge/convert) these via unix tools.

For the userlist: LDAP. Simply search for all objects which are users and have an email address.